# Conflicting signing certificate attributes present - Timestamp from TSA for PDF

Tags: x509certificate, bouncycastle, trusted-timestamp

Our TSA recently upgraded their TSA servers, but this is causing the "Conflicting signing certificate attributes present" error to occur when we attempt to Digitally Sign and Timestamp our PDFs (using C# code).

If I used the TSA's old server or SignFiles test server, then everything works as expected, but once I switch to the new server, then issues occur.

We are using SignFiles which looks to be a simple wrapper around BouncyCastle. The error occurs within the Bouncy Castle "Validate(...)" method.

[VS Code Showing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4x6Q.png)

I believe the error is happening as a result of the highlighted calls below.

[BouncyCastle Code - Validate(...) where error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Zx3.png)

At this point, I am a bit lost as I do not know what values the above code is checking, but I am thinking it might be the "Enhanced Key Usage" values.

If yes, then I see the following differences between the old Timestamp (left side) and the new one that does not work (right).

[Working and Non-Working Certificates Returned by TSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Uby.png)

Can anyone advise if this is the correct values that it is checking?

Can anyone advise why this error is happening and if its something that the TSA can correct within their settings and how the Timestamp is generated OR does Bouncy Castle need to be updated to work with new TSA servers?

We are continuing to use the legacy servers, but need to get this fixed to take advantage of the new faster servers.

I only found one other question regarding this at:
http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Time-Stamp-with-both-SigningCertificate-and-SigningCertificateV2-td3457605.html

Thank you,

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your client library is internally using BouncyCastle older than 1.8 which was incorrectly processing timestamps. As you have correctly found out this problem was reported (by me) in [JIRA issue 85](http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BMA-85) and fixed in BouncyCastle 1.8.

Original [RFC3161](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) compliant timestamps included only `SigningCertificate` (OID `1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.12`) CMS attribute with SHA-1 hash of TSA certificate. But since whole world abandoned SHA-1, [RFC5035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5035.txt) updated RFC3161 and allowed the usage of `SigningCertificateV2` (OID `1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47`) CMS attribute with SHA-256 (or any other) hash of TSA certificate. It also allowed the usage of both attributes at the same time to support legacy clients that may not support new hash algorithms. So IMO it is perfectly OK for TSA to include both attributes.

You have two options:

1. Ask the provider of your client library to upgrade it to BouncyCastle 1.8 where [the issue has been fixed](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/release-1.8.1/crypto/src/tsp/TimeStampResponse.cs#L157-L163). IMO this would be easier.
2. Ask your timestamp provider to reconfigure their TSA server so it does not include both CMS attributes in timestamps it generates. IMO this would be harder.

Let me know if something is not clear enough or you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In our case, we are using the latest package from SignFiles (https://www.signfiles.com/signature-library/) which I would assume has the latest Bouncy Castle code?

The highlighted code I found above is NOT from my machine, but rather from looking up that error and finding that code with the error message.

I will verify that my code is updated.

Comment: Is the "Enhanced Key.." the Signing Cert as I thought? From the values you provided, it looks like I am wrong. Where would I find the Signing Certificate values that you indicate?

Is there a reason why they would want to include both Signing Certificates? 
(I want a valid reason for them to change these values without causing issues for other clients)

Thank you

Comment: @user2032 well then it looks like package from SignFiles uses old BouncyCastle code.

Comment: @user2032 `SigningCertificate` and `SigningCertificateV2` are CMS attributes. They are not in present in TSA certificate. They are present in each issued timestamp. You can read more about them in [RFC5035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5035.txt).

Comment: @user2032 I've updated my answer to provide more details.

Comment: Thank you "Jariq".
SignFiles was able to correct their code quickly (good support and free update). Thanks for the information.